# how to down sample a narrow band signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, iot

I have a narrow band signal, 100 Hz and I sample it with SDR dongle and sampling frequency of 250 k. As the signal is ultra narrow band I can't convert it to 100 Hz by down sampling or filter and down sample?could you please help me?

[image: Signal]

the image above is my signal after sampling. i can read the signal as it is dbpsk modulation but after down sampling it will be destroyed.

Comment: Down sampling without previous lowpass filtering will result in aliasing ( folding the higher frequencies into your frequency band of interest). Start with a CIC filter with a down sampling factor of 25 and perhaps order 3. As you are doing it offline you can also consider to take a very sharp IIR filter and then down sample it. Take also a look at `decimate`. In general you should inform yourself more about down/up sampling and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try to design a high order low pass filter at 110Hz cutoff freq by [designfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/designfilt.html)
then [filter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html?searchHighlight=filter&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) it and then [resample](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) it in 250hz (it cannot be lower than nyquist frequency).

Comment: thankas alot but could you please help me more . I design this filter: nb_filter = designfilt('lowpassfir', 'FilterOrder', 50, ...
                 'CutoffFrequency', 110, ...
                 'PassbandRipple', 1, 'StopbandAttenuation', 60, ...
                 'SampleRate', 250e3); and then i resample(mysignal,1,2500) but it's  not working.could you please give me more suggestion?I would you so thankful

Comment: Sorry, I missed your "dbpsk modulation" note above. I don't know if the [comm.DBPSKDemodulator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.dbpskdemodulator-system-object.html) is helpful to you.
Could you upload a piece of your data to dropbox or something?

Comment: could you please look at this file in dropbox? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n6qgr9rdpm32hjx/AAAeZpESxE1lzAEYFmxic9bda?dl=0   -   I've used the dbpsk demodulation  but my problem is before demodulation part. in the mfile there are some filters i have used, in comment. thanks a lot